# Tab menu with image background using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have created a wizard using bootstrap and some custom styling

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/a7dRc/3/)

All I want to do now is add a couple of dashes (-) between the tabs

```
[One]----[2]----[3]
```

Can someone please help me out here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Add them after your `<a>` tag

Like this:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><span id="t1" class="textColor">1</span></a>-----------

            </li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="textColor">2</span></a>-------

            </li>
            <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"><span class="textColor">3</span></a>----
```